# Mysema Querydsl: Force path generation for Transient fields of type List

Tags: jpa

In a JPA model I have a field of type `List<T>` marked with `@Transient` where `T` is a generic type that extends `Foo`.

According to this bug report, https://bugs.launchpad.net/querydsl/+bug/784403,
I can mark the field with `@QueryType(PropertyType.SIMPLE)` to force the path to generate. This works great with String fields. Experimentation has shown I can even use `@QueryType(PropertyType.Entity)` for Entity typed fields. However, I do not know what `PropertyType` to use with Lists.

If I do set the `PropertyType` to `SIMPLE`, the path generates, but its type is `SimplePath<java.util.List<? extends Foo>>`  instead of `ListPath<Foo, QFoo>`